# Generate a crystal report from values on a windows form

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, vb.net-2010

I am new to VB.Net, i am just creating an application for logging equipment in and out. Each item will have a unique ID, after receiving the item the system has to generate the material acceptance report. and now i have to create the report using CR by getting the parameter / value from windows form.

For Eg: If i select that unique id from windows forms CR to generate report based on the selection.

Comment: Please show your VB code with your current approach.

Comment: yes it is possible, just pass the selection formula or a query to the report source, and call the report!..